# SQLCMD in Dynamic SQL?

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql, sqlcmd

Does anyone know if it's possible to use SQLCMD within dynamic SQL?   I think this is something PowerShell could do, which I'll try if it's not possible in TSQL.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
USE [master]
GO

DECLARE @LinkedServerName NVARCHAR(100) = N'MyServer'
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL = ':connect SQL-D-16T3022' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(13)
SET @SQL = @SQL + 'EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N''' +     @LinkedServerName + ''', @srvproduct=N''' + @LinkedServerName + ''', @provider=N''OraOLEDB.Oracle'', @datasrc=N''' + @LinkedServerName + ''''

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
-->  Incorrect syntax near ':'.
```

That results in a syntax error, which makes sense because the execution of the dynamic sql code isn't in SQLCMD mode.

Any way to make this happen?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you could display the value of @SQL just  before the moment of failure and include that here.

Comment: `SQLCMD` is a command prompt utility. I don't see anywhere in your codes above using `SQLCMD`

Comment: Also, the code is missing the point of using `sp_executesql` by injecting the parameters into the query rather than referring to the parameters in the query.